# pandas add a value column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have this simple problem but for some reason it's giving a headache.  I want to add a existing Date column with another column to get a newDate column.

For example:  I have Date and n columns, and I want to add in NewDate column into my existing df.

df:

```
Date         n     NewDate (New Calculation here: Date + n)    
05/31/2017   3     08/31/2017  
01/31/2017   4     05/31/2017
12/31/2016   2     02/28/2017
```

I tried:

```
df['NewDate'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + MonthEnd(n))
```

but I get an error saying "cannot convert the series to class 'int'

Comment: Can you post a full error traceback?

Comment: @MaxU I don't think so since I changed it using dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: Does `pd.to_datetime(df.Date) + (pd.to_timedelta(df.n, unit='M'))` not work?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yep, i think this is it

Comment: @MaxU I was hesitant at first, because the output isn't identical to OP's expected output, but looking at it again, probably a typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for an addition with a `timedelta` object.

```
v = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) + (pd.to_timedelta(df.n, unit='M'))
v

0   2017-08-30 07:27:18
1   2017-06-01 17:56:24
2   2017-03-01 20:58:12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

At the end, you can convert the result back into the same format as before -

```
df['NewDate'] = v.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```